# how to match a string from editText and a string in firebase database and return matched or not matched?

Tags: android

iam beginner, am working on simple project, i want  take user input from Edit Text and compare it to a string in firebase database, if they identical it return string matched, if not, it return not available in database, i dont know the codes but here i how far i go, need help

here are my codes

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View alertTextMuamala = inflater.inflate(R.layout.muamala_dialog, null);
    final EditText movieMuamala = alertTextMuamala.findViewById(R.id.movie_muamala);






    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Welcome!"); // this will dplay title

    //view dialog_muamala in alert

    alert.setView(alertTextMuamala);

    //this will prevent dialog cancel from back button

    alert.setCancelable(false);

    //this will set a cancel button

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Canceld!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    alert.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // to take user input as string

            String MovieMuamala = movieMuamala.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(MovieMuamala)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tafadhali Paste SMS ya Malipo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return ;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Muamala Umetumwa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();


}
```

on xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:text="@string/dilog"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/movie_muamala"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialog_info"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/movie_muamala"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:hint="Muamala:"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textColorHint="#AEB9F3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dialog_info"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_info" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37942488/13766961) to know how to get the string from the Firebase database.
assign that value to a string. Ex `String firebaseString = <retrieved string>;`
and pass that string to method like this `compare(firebaseString);`

you can get returned string as `String returnedstring = compare(firebaseString);`
in `returnedstring` you get either **String matched** or **not available in database**

Now use this method

```
public String compare(String firebase){
  String localString = movie_muamala.getText().toString();
  if(localString.equalsIgnoreCase(firebase)){
   return "String matched";
  }else{
   return "not available in database";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to get through

```
final String MovieMuamala = movieMuamala.getText().toString().trim();
            Muamala.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String pass = snapshot.child("muamala").getValue().toString();

                    if(MovieMuamala.equals(pass)) {



                        Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, "Pass Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        successNotification();


                        TextView subText = findViewById(R.id.sub_txt);
                        subText.setText(MovieMuamala);

                        
                    } else if (!MovieMuamala.equals(pass)){
                        Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, "Your Muamala Did not Match In Our Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: this gives me null and crash my app extView subText = findViewById(R.id.sub_txt);
                        subText.setText(MovieMuamala);  help please